# Node.js Knex SQL insert is too slow

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a basic login system that does the following:

- Checks if the username exists (goes OK)
- Inserts the username

After the insert, I select the `id` of the inserted `username`. This goes correct on the first login, but when I logout and login with a new username, the insert is too slow, causing my select to throw an exception, because the insert is not done yet. How can I fix this?

My code:

Database.js:

```
getPlayerByName (username) {
    return this.knex("penguins").first("*").where("username", username)
}
getPlayerExistsByName (username) {
    return this.knex("penguins").where("username", username).select("username")
}
insertPlayer (username) {
    return this.knex("penguins").insert({username: username}).then(() => {
        Logger.info(`Inserted ${username}`)
    }).catch((err) => {
        Logger.error(err)
    })
}
```

Login.js:

```
function handlePlayer (username, res) {
    database.getPlayerExistsByName(username).then(result => {
        if (result.length != 1) { // Username does not exist
            database.insertPlayer(username) // Insert username
            database.getPlayerByName(username).then(penguin => {
                return write(`&id=${penguin.id}&m=${penguin.mod}${Errors.OK}`, res) // I need the id here
            })
        } else {
            return write(Errors.NAME_UNAVAILABLE, res)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async funcion in the callback of then and use await in insert and get user to do this 2 methods synchronous

Comment: How can I use async and await for knex? Any references?

Comment: I didnt use knex but i think It return a promise you can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona